# Getting an error thrown from my loader function in Remixjs on the browser

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, remix.run

Here is what my route component and its loader function looks like:

```
import { LoaderFunctionArgs, json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import { unverifiedAccountsColleciton } from "~/db";

interface JsonResponse {
  success: boolean;
  message: string;
}

export default function VerifyEmailPage() {
  const data = useLoaderData();
  console.log(data);

  return <>Hello</>;
}

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);

  const id = url.searchParams.get("id");

  console.log(id);

  if (id === null || id === "") {
    const res: JsonResponse = {
      success: false,
      message: "Bad request",
    };

    return json(res);
  }

  // see if unverified account exists
  const u = await unverifiedAccountsColleciton.findOne({
    _id: new ObjectId(id),
  });
  if (u === null) {
    const res: JsonResponse = {
      success: false,
      message: "Bad request",
    };

    return json(res);
  }

  return json(u);
}
```

There is no errors at build time and I'm still able to access this route, but in my browser's console I get this error message:

```
code-points-data.ts:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at node_modules/@mongodb-js/saslprep/dist/code-points-data.js (code-points-data.ts:4:3)
    at __require2 (chunk-PZDJHGND.js:18:50)
    at node_modules/@mongodb-js/saslprep/dist/memory-code-points.js (memory-code-points.ts:2:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PZDJHGND.js:18:50)
    at node_modules/@mongodb-js/saslprep/dist/index.js (index.ts:1:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PZDJHGND.js:18:50)
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js (scram.ts:1:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PZDJHGND.js:18:50)
    at node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js (connect.ts:27:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-PZDJHGND.js:18:50)
```

I removed this part of the code from my loader function and everything works fine with no error, I just return null at the end instead of json(u):

```
// see if unverified account exists
  const u = await unverifiedAccountsColleciton.findOne({
    _id: new ObjectId(id),
  });
  if (u === null) {
    const res: JsonResponse = {
      success: false,
      message: "Bad request",
    };

    return json(res);
  }

  return json(u);
```

This seems to be a mongodb related error, I'm new to Remix (loving it so far) and was wondering why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your *db* file to `db.server.ts`. This will ensure that the MongoDB code is only in your server bundle. It looks like it was added to your client bundle, hence the `Buffer is not defined` error.

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/gotchas#server-code-in-client-bundles

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems to still be throwing the same error. Do you think that I might have to move all the server related files outside the app directory?

Answer (score 0):

thanks to kiliman, I have now read through some more remix documentation and got it to work by not importing anything from monogdb package, I have to export custom functions from my own *.server.ts file and then I can use that within the loader function with no errors